# How to create a day counter for android application?

Tags: android

I want to add a day counter feature to my android application, basically when user set the counter, it starts counting how many days passed until they click reset. I've tried to use default chronometer but it stopped when user stops the application, I want it to count days even the app is not active.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   private Chronometer chronometer;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
         ((Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
         ((Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
          switch(v.getId()) {
          case R.id.start_button:
                 chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                 chronometer.start();
                 break;
         case R.id.stop_button:
                chronometer.stop();
                break;
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to put it in a service(https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html). This way it will run even when the app is stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuo Can Save a string with the Number of date and increment it every day, use sharedpreference.
It's an option.

[Click here for an example of sharedpreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840391/how-can-i-permanently-store-a-value-from-a-preference-screen)

Answer (score 0):

For the goal you want , you should use persistence storage in android like SQLiteDatabase , Sharedpreferences etc.

**Once user clicks on start button then store current date or datetime in table and whenever user will open the app then we can get difference between current datetime and the datetime of stored in table.We can convert it into days after that.**

I hope this will help you for getting better idea. Feel free to comment.